# Why does my antivirus program not detect this malicious behavior?

Tags: fork, antivirus

I wrote this C program and ran on my Windows system. My system hanged and not even Task manager was opening. Finally, I had to reboot. This is clearly a malicious program, but my antivirus does not detect this. Why?

```
#include<unistd.h>
main() {
while(1)
    fork();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers don't typically use AV software due to the huge speed penalty, or at least they disable it on the filesystem subtree they work in.

But even so, that isn't the sort of pattern AV software tries to detect. The AV software looks for files you are reading and writing and changes to system state, or specific identified viruses or their prior identified signatures.

And how would it decide, anyway? From the point of view of a program there would be a fine line between an overloaded web server and a fork bomb.

Finally, this sort of behavior is kind of self-correcting. If we really had viruses arriving with nothing more damaging than a fork bomb we might just declare victory and say "don't run that".

BTW, did you run the fork bomb as administrator?

Comment: Ya I ran as administrator but will it make difference otherwise?

Comment: Typically the numbers of procs a non-admin can start is limited by the kernel.

Answer (score 6):

Antivirus programs don't recognize malicious behavior - they recognize patterns of know viruses *that are already in the wild* (file names, process names, binary signatures, etc.).

This is why they can often be subverted since they are a reactive solution to an evolving problem.

Comment: But this is such a basic thing means forking processes. Cant they even detect this?

Comment: Furthermore, your snippet is hardly a virus since it doesn't have any abiity to reproduce itself.  Would this payload be injected in some virus framework of sort, and would it spread sufficiently, anti-viral software companies would then identify it and its patterns and add it to their list.

Comment: Although some virus programs do have heuristic checking that can check for viral-like behavior (like attempting to write into program memory space).

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not a virus, because it cannot spread itself, that is, it can't infect other files/computers

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not malicious behavior, looks more like a logic error in your code. I wish there will be an antivirus one day that could detect applications, drivers, ms updates, ms products that cause BSOD's =)

Comment: This is not a logical error. I have written it intentionally for testing.

Comment: nothing personal, but there is no sanity in this code. It doesn't harm nor does anything productive.